# Multiplatform project with shared module

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to create a multi platform project with a shared dependency, but I cannot find out what I am doing wrong.

The background is I want to create a library which generated some kind of configuration and uses that configuration for a runtime library which should run on jvm and node.js. So the configuration data classes can be shared which I want to put in a shared module. That code is not platform specific at all. The configuration generation (I call that CLI) should be jvm only. So I have this modules (with the plugin names):

- cli (org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm)
- shared (kotlin-platform-common)
- runtime-shared (kotlin-platform-common)
- runtime-js (kotlin-platform-js)
- runtime-jvm (kotlin-platform-jvm)

I setup the module shared as dependency via `compile project(":shared")`, but it seems that none of the classes of shared are in the classpath of the modules starting with runtime.

Is that not yet possible or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To connect a *common* module (i.e. one built with `kotlin-platform-common`) with its platform-specific implementations, you should provide those with an `expectedBy project(':shared')` dependency instead of a `compile` one.

You can find an example build script in the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html#setting-up-a-multiplatform-project) or in some of the available sample projects, like [here](https://github.com/hhariri/kotlin-mpp-sample/blob/master/build.gradle#L54).

Comment: Cool that works, but that is not very intuitive. I still do not get why the platform specific implementation should be *expected by* another module which is providing classes for the implementation.

Comment: The naming here follows the `expect`/`actual` terminology of Kotlin multiplatform projects, where a common module contains declarations which are *expected* to get platform-specific implementations in the platform modules. Those are, therefore, *expected by* the common module.